# Laravel Auth::attempt function not working

Tags: php, ajax, authentication, laravel

I am trying to use the Laravel attempt function within the Auth class to allow a user to login and store themselves in the session.

I understand this function requires an array with the 'password' and 'email' variables and I am sending this fine, it just doesn't seem to be logging me in or returning true.

Here is my controller code:

```
class LoginController extends BaseController {
    public function login()
    {       
        if(isset($_POST)) {     
            $errorsArray = array();
            foreach($_POST as $key => $postItem) {
                if(empty($postItem) || $postItem == "") {
                    $errorsArray[] = array(
                        'errorItem' => $key,
                        'errorMessage' => "Please enter a value for " .ucfirst($postItem)
                    );
                }
            }
            if(!empty($errorsArray)) {
                $returnArray = array( 
                    'didLog' => false,
                    'errors' => $errorsArray 
                );
            } else {

                if(Auth::attempt(array('username' => $_POST['username'], 'password' => $_POST['password']))) {
                    die("here");
                } else {
                    die("no");
                }

            }
            return json_encode($returnArray);
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see above, I am checking to see if the inputs are valid, and if so, calling the Auth::attempt function in order to log a user in.

The view code:

```
<form>
        <h3><i class="lock"></i>Please enter your login details</h3>
        <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="email" data-required=1 />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" data-required=1 />
        <input type="submit" value="login" />   
        <button>Signup with Facebook</button>
        <button>Signup with Twitter</button>
        <a href="#" class="close-overlay" data-related="login-overlay">CLOSE</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
```

And the appropriate Javascript code

```
            jQuery.ajax({
                type     : "post",
                dataType : "json",
                url      : url,
                data     : "username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
                success  : function(data) {
                    if(data.didLog == true) {
                        alert("rrue");
                    } else {
                        alert("false");
                    }
                }
            });
```

And I have die(print_r(()) the input (which is present in my database) as follows:

```
Array
```

(
    [username] => jamesholman@bigwavemedia.co.uk
    [password] => password
)

And the appropriate record in the database

[image]

I am getting a "no" (which is a fail in my code) when attempting to login. Can anyone see where I am going wrong as I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't work!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you logging in with "jamesholman@bigwavemedia.co.uk" or "jamesholman" as your username? The Auth::attempt is pointing `$_POST['username']` to your username column in your database table. So if you're trying to authenticate with 'jamesholman@bigwavemedia.co.uk' as your username, it won't find any user

Comment: Ok, I changed that line to "if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => $_POST['username'], 'password' => $_POST['password']))) {" and am still getting a fail. Does this function hash the password? Thanks

Comment: Yes, auth::attempt() checks for hashed password, so plain text password will not work.

Comment: Yeah i think you should try hash the password input: `Hash::make($_POST['password'])`, then also hash the stored password in your database.

Comment: There's no need to do `Hash::make($_POST['password'])` in auth::attempt() parameter (it will be done automatically), but in database there must be a hasn, not a plain text.

Comment: My mistake, of course. You just need to store a hashed password

Comment: You should use Laravel's build in function to access post and get parameters, by calling `Input::get('username')` and `Input::get('password')`

Comment: Ok after making the changes above and using the User object to re-save the user in the database, the Auth function now works correctly. I will accept this answer as this was the problem in the first place.